# error when trying to convert

Tags: python, string, type-conversion, int

I am trying to write my first intro software too python and i can't get the convert part to work. I want it to convert my varibale name from **str** too an **int**

```
print('Name: ')
name = input()
print('Age: ')
age = input()
print('Sex: ')
sex = input()
print('Your name is ' + name + ' ,your age is ' + age + ' and your sex is ' + sex)
int(str(name))
x = len(name)
print('Your name have ' + x + 'letters')
```

the error that i am getting looks like this

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 's'
```

Comment: Are you on python 2 or 3? Can you post the entire traceback so we can see which line its on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be doing:

```
len(name)
```

Instead of:

```
int(str(name))
```

Your error is just as it says:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 's'
```

You cannot convert `'s'`, a string value, to an integer.

Answer (score 0):

You cant convert a string to an int, however, if you get len(name) it should return the length of the string